# Merging Collections with multiple keys in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm collating data from an external API in Laravel 5.7 and need to collate data from 3 methods into one row using Eloquent (I don't make these rules). These functions currently return collections, where I need to merge them into one collection then place in the database. I have common parameters being the following between all the collections:

```
[uniqueID, date]
```

This is because I will be getting multiple of the same uniqueID but with different dates - so the uniqueness is the combination of a date + uniqueID.

Here's a pseudocode example of what I want to achieve realistically:

```
public function getParamSet1()
{
    // some code gets the params to put into this collection
    // this is a fairly big pull and has a few nested loops to
    // put values into the below collection.
    $aggregateParamSet1 = collect(['param1', 'uniqueID', 'date', ]);
    return aggregateParamSet1;
}

public function getParamSet2()
{
    // some code gets the params to put into this collection
    // this is a fairly big pull and has a few nested loops to
    // put values into the below collection.
    $aggregateParamSet2 = collect(['param2', 'uniqueID', 'date', ]);
    return $aggregateParamSet2;
}

public function getParamSet3()
{
    // some code gets the params to put into this collection
    // this is a fairly big pull and has a few nested loops to
    // put values into the below collection.
    $aggregateParamSet3 = collect(['param3', 'uniqueID', 'date', ]);
    return $aggregateParamSet3;

}

public function writeToDB()
{
    $collection1 = getParamSet1();
    $collection2 = getParamSet2();
    $collection3 = getParamSet3();
    // merge these collections then update/create the records with
    // Eloquent

}
```

Being someone not too familiar with Laravel makes me think that I should have a separate field in the collections that merges the date + ID to create a truly UniqueID and merge based on that keyword if I understand the Collection documents correctly, however I think there must be a better, more efficient way of doing this? Would appreciate a sanity check with some ways of managing 3 calls with different data being returned (with a common ID and date) that needs to be collated into a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the data to the database for each paramSet using the `Model::updateOrCreate($where, $update)` eloquent method.  Stuff the `uniqueId` and `date` into the `$where` array and the rest of the data into the `$update` array.  This will keep all the DB entries for the Model unique for each date-uniqueID combo.

Comment: Thanks - I was just puzzled whether that was the best way to approach it if I happened to be collecting a lot of entries to each collection - whether it was better to make a bigger collection then commit with Eloquent  updatecreate - but this way is pretty simple.